# How to import particular file from directories if it contain more than 200,000 files

Tags: files

let consider I'm having directories which having more than 200,000 files. It take too much time to open that particular directory. If I know the file name from this and I want to take copy of this file from my server directories to local desktop directories.

I'm having directory name as "log"
in this I'm having 200,000 files (from 2015 to current date) with filename as "xyz_ddmmyyhhssmi" format 
so here 
Case 1::: if i know the exact file name Or
Case 2 ::: if I know any unique word from today's log file i.e "xyz_currenttimestamp" 
then how I copy this file from my server to my local drive in above 2 cases

Comment: Most folks outside India don't know what a lakh is.

Comment: Is there any way you could identify the file?  I mean, if you don't have the file name, even manually sifting through 200000 files sounds like na impossible task.

Comment: please see my edited questions

Comment: More than 200K files in a directory is Bad System Design. Known to cause GUI tools to, for EACH file, look at the file, decide which icon goes with the file,  and load the icon. 200,000 times! A comand line tool could do this in a trice. `cp source_dir/long_strange_filename_191205123422 destination_dir/`

Comment: @waltinator i know this cp syntax but here i want to copy server file from server to my local system directory

Comment: Then use `scp` or `ftp`. I don't really understand your question. Is it "how to get a file from a remote server"?

Comment: First use `locate` to get exact spelling then copy and paste it into copy command. Eg `locate xyz_ddmmyy*` or the closest name you can think of followed by `*`. You can use `*` at the beginning of a file name too or specify a path at the front.

Comment: here my problem will solve by using scp or ftp so please provide command to solve this

Comment: "Please provide a command".  You could also read documentation, but fine:  On your desktop (not the server):  `scp yourusername@serverhost:/full/path/to/desired/file .` This will copy the file named `/full/path/to/desired/file` on the server named `serverhost` with the access rights of `yourusername` to the current directory (`.`) on your desktop machine.